# 2007 Hyundai Sonata Automatic Key Won't Turn

Tags: ignition, hyundai, sonata

1. This started before the steering wheel was locked, I locked it because I forgot what a locked steering wheel feels like and wasn't thinking too much. Had a LOT of time to wiggle the key before it was locked though, so it's definitely the ignition lock cylinder.
2. Tried with a never used key - didn't solve the problem.

> Pop the cylinder assembly out of column lock, and take it to locksmith.. maybe $25 repair, as opposed to $160+ for new cylinder assembly with key, thus making you a 2 key car then.

According to some [Hyundai Forum](http://www.autozone.com/1/categories/hyundai-sonata-ignition-lock-cylinders), you can just get it repaired at a locksmith. Is this correct?

Also, extremely I rusty mechanically (nor did I ever deal with a wheel lock), but I remember something about the steering wheel lock being a huge problem for me now as I go to take the cylinder out, might have to drill the spring release. Is this correct or is that not an issue?

Edit - I guess I don't understand what actually breaks. I understand how locks work and a worn down key just won't move the pins and allow it to turn - fine. That seems to not be the problem though, what else is there to break and keep it from turning?

Comment: Are you sure the steering wheel isn't just binding on the key mechanism? Try wiggling the *steering wheel* while trying to turn the key ... might be a revelation.

Comment: I am sure because I tried it for 20 minutes on two separate times before I locked the wheel. I will try more, but I am 90% sure.

Comment: Try and squirt some lubricant into the cylinder, like WD-40. Shouldn't take a whole bunch.

Comment: WD-40 is the worst part of working on cars for me. Used to use liquid wrench on suspensions, dat smell. Will try, thanks.

Comment: Dry graphite will do a good job as well. And it doesn't smell. It's just most people don't keep graphite on hand, while they do have some sort of lubricant.

Comment: Thanks man, I think I will go buy some. Would be awesome if I don't have to fix this tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Paulster2: Dry graphite did the trick. I am surprised, since the "easy" solution never works for me. Turns without any effort now. Am I to assume one of the pins got jammed in its cylinder (whatever the technical name for it is)? Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: That is exactly what you can assume. If one of the "pins" (I don't remember what it's called either) gets stuck, that's exactly what can happen. Also, just because it's an easy fix does not mean you should discount it. I'm glad that it worked for you!

Comment: FYI, 2007 Sonata ignition switch is in the dash, not the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet the cylinder is only stuck. You can probably get it to work again by using some type of lubricant. That could be either WD-40 (just a little bit ... don't want to soak the thing) or if you don't like the smell, try some dry graphite.